# Sonata Admin Bundle delete not working in prod

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a following issue: if I try to delete something in sonata admin in prod enviroment after confirmation screen and pressing "yes, delete" nothing happens. In dev everything works fine. Could it be a caching issue? Any settings I could try?

Comment: pls. first of all clear the cache after try that.

Comment: I did, didn't help :(

Comment: did you check your prod log in logs/ or eventually your php_errors ?

Comment: no errors :( just coming back to confirmation page

Comment: if I comment out "$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);" in app.php everithing works, so it's a caching issue but found still no sollution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is in the code that detecting the request method. It should detect DELETE method but it detects all delete operations as POST method instead.

Add this line of code in your app.php to fix this:

```
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
```

it can be after $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

Comment: We have the same problem as @jeff.
Can you explain why it does work on dev and accept, but not in production and why this code fixxes it?
Can this code have any (unwanted) effects on other parts of our application?

Comment: It lets the POST methods with a delete header to be translated as a DELETE method. Some servers only support GET and POST while Sonata works with DELETE method. This can also help other bundles that work with PUT or PATCH work fine with POST and is pretty straight forward for Rest Servers and HTTP Servers and I don't see any issue with it.