# Sonata Admin: Can't create new object in prod

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata, symfony-2.8

I have a problem here with sonata admin: can't create a new object of a certain model in production environment, but it does not throw any error or exception to track the problem. When I try to create with app_dev.php enabled everything works just fine.

Tried cleaning cache and all. Nothing happens.

I tried this solution too: [Sonata Admin Bundle delete not working in prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248992/sonata-admin-bundle-delete-not-working-in-prod)
but the problem still persists.

Symfony 2.8 with Sonata Admin in Nginx Server. Other models work fine too.

Any help please? I have no clue where must be the problem :(

EDIT:

I got this in logs:

2018/03/15 13:55:43 [error] 12984#0: *11647 NAXSI_FMT: ip="LOLip"&server="lolmyweb.com"&uri=/admin/product/productlink/create&learning=0&vers=0.55.3&total_processed=13310&total_blocked=35&block=1&cscore0=$RFI&score0=8&zone0=BODY&id0=1101&var_name0=s5aaa7b4711a0e[link], client: 80.38.196.155, server: "lolmyweb.com, request: "POST /admin/product/productlink/create?uniqid=s5aaa7b4711a0e HTTP/1.1", host: "lolmyweb.com", referrer: "lolmyweb.com/admin/product/productlink/create"

No idea what that means...

Comment: Nothing in logs?

Comment: @kunicmarko20 There I edited and added the last one (sure it is related) but no idea what it could mean

Comment: This doesn't look like symfony logs, anything in app/logs/prod

Comment: Nope, Symfony doesn't capture the error :S. The one above are from nginx logs (the only one that it seems that can register something about it).

Comment: @kunicmarko20 Any idea?

Comment: I can't help without logs, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just commented the naxsi.rules line in my nginx.conf:

```
location / {
  # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;
  # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
  try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Not really sure if I've done right tho :/